# How can I convert a string with the emoji name into a discord emoji?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Let's say I have a string with an emoji name, for example `emoji = 'fishing_pole_and_fish'`.

Is there a way to do `msg.add_reaction(emoji)` without getting the error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10014): Unknown
> Emoji

Or can I convert the string to a `discord.Emoji`?

I know I could use `'\N{FISHING POLE AND FISH}'`, but I need it as `'fishing_pole_and_fish'` so I can do other things with it. Also, fishing pole and fish is just an example emoji

Comment: As an alternative, can you use the unicode character for the emoji? So for `:fishing_pole_and_fish:` this would be . Or do you specifically need the text?

Comment: I guess I'll just change my whole setup... I really wish you could use emoji names for add_reaction() though

Comment: Somehow using those unicode characters completely breaks IDLE

Comment: Wouldn't `def string_to_emoji(string): return r"\N{%s}"%string` work then?

Comment: That just creates the string `"\\N{FISHING POLE AND FISH}"` instead of the actual emoji.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked in to the [emoji module](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/)?

For the bot to be able to react with the standard built in emojis, it needs the emojis to be the symbol " ", not ":fishing_pole:", that only works with custom emojis `<:name:id>`.

```
import emoji

string = ":fishing_pole:"
demoji = emoji.demojize(" ")   # This takes the emoji and gives--> :fishing_pole:
emoji = emoji.emojize(string)    # This takes :fishing_pole: and gives-->     
print(demoji)
print(emoji)
```

It does require having ":" on either side, otherwise it wont work. But that you can add with `''.join(":"+string+":")` if needed

Comment: This is probably a "Discord being weird" issue, but this module doesn't line up with what Discord's doing. It doesn't handle individual regional indicator emojis at all, instead looking up the code for paired indicators as a flag ("us" returns ":United_States:"), and other emojis have incorrect (from Discord's POV) names: ":a:" ends up getting the name ":A_button_(blood_type):". Other emojis seem to be fairly accurate, like smilies and hand signs, though even those can have subtlely incorrect names ("thumbsup" becomes "thumbs_up"). Mind you I'm using demojize for all of this testing.

Comment: @Elusivehawk I've been testing it a bit now, The flags turn out weird, but regional indicators can be used by using aliases. `emoji.demojize(text, use_aliases=True)` It give `regional_indicator_a` instead of `regional_indicator_symbol_letter_a`. I haven't tested with all of emojis, but it seems aliases work slightly better

Comment: I think I found the problem. It seems as though the module only makes regular expressions for emojis defined in the "primary" emoji table. So in the case of the regional indicators, they're only defined in the aliases table. End result: it sees a regional indicator, tries to make a pattern for it, can't, and passes by it. I need to study the code further to turn this into a pull request, but this bug is bothering me enough I'm willing to try and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`unicodedata.lookup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.lookup) function:

```
from unicodedata import lookup

def emoji_from_name(name):
    return lookup(name.replace("_", " "))
```

Comment: When I use it on some emojis it doesn't work, e.g. for :thinking: `KeyError: "undefined character name 'thinking'"`

Comment: That's because the name of that character is `thinking face`.  Discord uses some non-standard names.  Where are you getting the strings from?

Comment: Ohhhhh. I define the strings myself, so I can reformat them for other purposes

Answer (score 0):

For custom emojis in the guild you can use this. keep in mind you must have the emoji in the guild.

```py
emoji = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.emojis, name="CUSTOM EMOJI NAME")
```

Other alternative is to use the [bot.get_emoji](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_emoji#discord.Client.get_emoji) which takes the id of the emoji, you can use this to have across guild custom emojis